# UICollectionViewCell executing statements if isSelected is true when it never is

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a shop as a UICollectionView. I have a system of highlighting the current ball the user will use. There cells can be owned or not owned. When I click on a not owned, if the user does not have enough money to buy it, nothing should happen, and if they do, isSelected should be set to true. The problem is when I click on a locked item, it still gets highlighted, but none of the breakpoints trigger inside the if statement to test if it is bought. I have a didSet on isSelected to highlight the cell.

This is my delegate class

This is a shortened version of the didSelectItemAt function:

```
//I have an array of structs, called balls, to hold values of each item.


    indx = indexPath.item//Universal variable that can be accessed in both this class and the cell class

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! Shop1CollectionViewCell

    balls[indexPath.item].owned =  cell.clickedOn(price: balls[indexPath.item].price, index: indexPath.item)
//saves the value to know if you own that item and can select it whenever if you buy it it returns true if not, false

    if balls[indexPath.item].owned == true && cell.owned == true{
        //This will only pass if the item has been bought, so you can not select items that you don't own
        if ogCell.isSelected{
            ogCell.isSelected = false
         //deselects the saved cell, last selected from last time, that is saved from userdefaults

        }
    currentItem = indexPath.item//reference for the current item that is selected

       cell.isSelected = true
//this will trigger the highlight() function in didSet

        lastCell = cell//reference to last cell selected
        lastIndex = indexPath.item//index of that cell

    }
```

This is some of my cell class:

```
//This is what is executed when the isSelected is changed.

override var isSelected: Bool{
    didSet{
        if self.isSelected{

        highlight()

        }else{
            unHighlight()
        }

}
}


//This is what is executed when the cell is clicked on:


if money >= price && !owned{
        money -= price
        owned = true
        isSelected = true
    }else if owned == false{
        owned = false
        isSelected = false
        currentItem = lastIndex

        lastCell.highlight()
    }
```

When I click on the cell, I have created a way to deselect the selected cell if it is not owned, but this process deselects the previous selection, so I am left with nothing selected. I would like to know why the unowned cell is being highlighted, even when debugging says it never goes through any point that isSelected is set to true.

I can add more code if needed but all other code seemed unnecessary.

Comment: Selection involves highlighting. Tapping a cell highlights it. Basically you should not be trying to highlight or select individual cells; let the collection view manage that.

Comment: Is there a way to turn that on or off, because when I started, it never highlighted cells. I would need to customize it because I only want it to highlight owned items. Also, would there be a way to select programmatically?

Comment: It seems to me that you're misusing the built-in notion of highlighting to stand in for some sort of customizable state you want your cells to adopt. But a cell cannot hold state because it is view, and a reused view at that. Keep track of state in your model, communicate it thru the data source, implement it visually through the data source or the cell subclass.

Comment: Just to give an example, your q. says "There cells can be owned or not owned". You might just be abbreviating, but if you really mean that, you have a gross misconception. A cell cannot be anything. The model for that index path is what can be owned or not owned. The cell that temporarily slots into that index path is merely a temporary visual reflection of that.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying. I guess I meant each item can be owned or not owned, which is represented by one of the cells.

Comment: OK, understood. But I still think it's a mistake to make highlightedness stand in for some custom state you are trying to reflect.

Comment: Ok. I will take this into consideration. I will try to find another way to do this.